Connecting a Windows Machine to an Android Phone in c#
I'm using the InTheHand.Net library to connect Windows machine to an Android phone device.
There is the following issues.
1- When I connect two Android phones, using BluetoothServerSocket on one and BluetoothSocket on the other, the connectios is stablished without using the MAC addess in any of the two phones; it is only required that both machines have the same UUID.
1- When I connect one Android using BluetoothSocket as client and the Windows machine using  BluetoothListener as server, the connectios is stablished without using the MAC addess neither the Windows computer nor  the Android device and as in the numeral 1, only  the common GPUID is required.
3 - When the connectios is from Windows machine as client to Android phone as server, the Windows machine must use the Android device MAC address of the phone which it is connecting plus the common GPUID, becuase all the overloaded Connect() methods in the In "TheHand.Net" library   use the MAC  (ex: Connect(MAC_Address,GPUID)  ).
Question: Is there a method to connect Windows machine as client to an Android device as server without using  MAC in any of the two?
I tried many connections using the library: "InTheHand.Net" but any connection method of that library let me a connection witout using the Android server MAC.
I expect that some body recommend me another library or piece of code to resolves my issue.

No, there is no way. Bluetooth always uses MAC to connect to other device. On Android you already has BluetoothDevice object that knowns target MAC and then passes the MAC to socket when you call createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() or similar.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
